# How to press "ALT+S" in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to Send `ALT+S` Key event using Selenium Web Driver for an ``EditBox. Cursor Position is already set to EditBox I am using following code

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT+"S"))
```

but it's not giving me desired result. It's Typing character `'S'` in the Edit Box.
I have tried another code but got the same result.

```
Actions action =new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.ALT).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0053')).perform();
```

Thanks in Advance

I want to Add one more thing here. The code is working Properly in Firefox 12 but its not working properly in IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-browser issues are rather hard to investigate as they are specific to particular driver and not WebDriver API.

Another variant that might work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your editbox's XPath")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "s"));
```

As workaround I might recommend to take a look to AutoIT ([Official site](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)) or Robot ([Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html))

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It might work, I haven't tried though

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your editbox's XPath"))
      .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT + Keys.S));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Robot class of java

```
    try{
        Robot robot=new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);        
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer actually works and I have not found any other way to get the Alt key simulated.